# The meaning of `Variable(data.type(Tensor)).to(device)` on pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

Can someone explain to me what's the following line of code means `real_skeleton = Variable(data.type(Tensor)).to(device)` ? Thanks you

Comment: I just want to know what that whole line means ?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: What Variable package is used for ?  `data.type(Tensor)` ?

Answer (score 0):

- `Variable` deprecated PyTorch function, can be ignored.
- `.type(Tensor)` casts `data` with a Tensor default dtype.
- `.to(device)` sends the tensor storage to `device` (i.e. CPU, GPU etc)